# React Native latest version problem with windows 10

Tags: windows, react-native

I'm working on windows 10 and i want to create a new react-native project.

my node version is :

```
$ node -v
v14.0.0
```

my npm version :

```
$ npm -v
6.14.4
```

yarn version :

```
$ yarn -v
1.22.4
```

My system variables path :

[image: path]

When i run :

```
react-native init myproject
```

I got this error :

[image]

Comment: did you already tried running `npm install -g ansi-styles` before the `react-native init`?

Comment: yes i tried and i got the same error